# Slim 3 get current route in middleware

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

I want to get the name of the current I route in a middleware class. Previously (in Slim 2.*) you could fetch the current route like so:

`$route = $this->app->router->getCurrentRoute();`

But this function has been removed in the 3.0 version of Slim. I've found the following code in the `__invoke` method of `Slim\App`:

```
    // Get the route info
    $routeInfo = $request->getAttribute('routeInfo');

    /** @var \Slim\Interfaces\RouterInterface $router */
    $router = $this->container->get('router');

    // If router hasn't been dispatched or the URI changed then dispatch
    if (null === $routeInfo || ($routeInfo['request'] !== [$request->getMethod(), (string) $request->getUri()])) {
        $request = $this->dispatchRouterAndPrepareRoute($request, $router);
        $routeInfo = $request->getAttribute('routeInfo');
    }
```

This indicates that the current route is stored as the attribute `routeInfo` in the `Request`. But it seems that my custom middleware class is called before the attribute is set (by the `$this->dispatchRouterAndPrepareRoute($request, $router);` method). Because calling `$request->getAttribute('routeInfo')` resolves to `NULL`.

So my question is; how can I get the current route (or the name of the route) from a middleware function/class?

Or should I just copy the piece of code above from `Slim\App`?

Comment: I am also having trouble getting the current route in middleware. I have set the `'determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware' => true` and when I do `$route = $request->getAttribute('route');` I get an object(Slim\Route), but when I do  `$routeName = $route->getName();` I get null. Anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: Did you name the route via the `setName()` method? (https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#route-names)

Comment: Thx @Wessel. The problem was the missing `setName()` method after declaring the route.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Slim3, here is an example showing you how to get routing information from within middleware, which is actually a combination of previous answers put together.

```
<?php

$slimSettings = array('determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware' => true);

// This is not necessary for this answer, but very useful
if (ENVIRONMENT == "dev")
{
    $slimSettings['displayErrorDetails'] = true;
}

$slimConfig = array('settings' => $slimSettings);
$app = new \Slim\App($slimConfig);


$myMiddleware = function ($request, $response, $next) {

    $route = $request->getAttribute('route');
    $routeName = $route->getName();
    $groups = $route->getGroups();
    $methods = $route->getMethods();
    $arguments = $route->getArguments();

    print "Route Info: " . print_r($route, true);
    print "Route Name: " . print_r($routeName, true);
    print "Route Groups: " . print_r($groups, true);
    print "Route Methods: " . print_r($methods, true);
    print "Route Arguments: " . print_r($arguments, true);
};

// Define app routes
$app->add($myMiddleware);


$app->get('/', function (\Slim\Http\Request $request, Slim\Http\Response $response, $args) {
    # put some code here....
})
```

In my case, I wanted to add middleware that would ensure the user was logged in on certain routes, and redirect them to the login page if they weren't. I found the easiest way to do this was to use `->setName()` on the routes like so:

```
$app->get('/', function (\Slim\Http\Request $request, Slim\Http\Response $response, $args) {
    return $response->withRedirect('/home');
})->setName('index');
```

Then if this route was matched, the `$routeName` in the middleware example will be `"index"`. I then defined my array list of routes that didn't require authentication and checked if the current route was in that list. E.g.

```
if (!in_array($routeName, $publicRoutesArray))
{
    # @TODO - check user logged in and redirect if not.
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
$request->getUri()->getPath()
```

Get current Route, even in `middleware`.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently you can configure Slim to determine the route before going into the middleware with this setting:

```
$app = new Slim\App([
    'settings'  => [
        'determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware' => true,
    ]
]);
```

I'm not sure what kind of impact this has, but it works for me :)

Comment: Once you do this, using @SamarRizvi answer works with using `$routeInfo = $request->getAttribute('routeInfo');` inside the middleware. Without this, $routeInfo is nothing.

Comment: This is specifically for App middleware. Also, if the route *doesn't* exist then `$route` will be null in @SamarRizvi's answer with this setting change.

Answer (score 1):

Does the following provide you with sufficient information you require or do you also need the 'request' bit in routeInfo?

```
$app->getContainer()->get('router')->dispatch($req);
```

If you also require the 'request' bit then you will need to manually do the same thing `dispatchRouterAndPrepareRoute` does.

```
if ($routeInfo[0] === Dispatcher::FOUND) {
            $routeArguments = [];
            foreach ($routeInfo[2] as $k => $v) {
                $routeArguments[$k] = urldecode($v);
            }

            $route = $router->lookupRoute($routeInfo[1]);
            $route->prepare($request, $routeArguments);

            // add route to the request's attributes in case a middleware or handler needs access to the route
            $request = $request->withAttribute('route', $route);
        }

        $routeInfo['request'] = [$request->getMethod(), (string) $request->getUri()];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering! This solves my issue, but it didn't feel right because it's a more complex solution than the Slim 2.* approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you get current route in your middleware in Slim framework 3:

```
$routeInfo = $request->getAttribute('routeInfo');
```

Note that you should use this inside `__invoke()` function in your middleware. Here's the sample usage:

```
public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
    {
        ....
        $routeInfo = $request->getAttribute('routeInfo');
        ....
    }
```

$routeInfo shall then contain an object like:

```
{
    "0": 1,
    "1": "route6",
    "2": {
      "name": "loremipsum"
    },
    "request": [
      "POST",
      "http://example.org/loremipsum"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Slim 4, try this:

```
$route = $request->getAttribute('username');
```

Working Example:

```
$app->post('/test/[{username}]', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args){

$route = $request->getAttribute('username');
$response->getBody()->write(json_encode($route));
return $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')->withStatus(201);});
```

Read More on Routing in Slim 4: https://akrabat.com/routing-in-slim-4/

Comment: Use `$request->getAttributes();` to see the Attributes available in the Request.

Comment: The 'Slim App' is created using the below method: `$app = AppFactory::create();`